# How can I get a value from a multi-dimensional array using a string with combined keys?

Tags: php, arrays

Please see my code bellow, I want to get `$arr['jimmy']['age']` here. The string is `jimmy.age` which will be posted from ajax

```
<?php
$arr=array(
    'jimmy'=>array(
        'age'=>31
    )
);

$str='jimmy.age';
$keys_tree=explode('.',$str);
$x='';
foreach($keys_tree as $k=>$v){
    $x.='["'.$v.'"]';
}
echo $arr$x; //error here; how can i get $arr['jimmy']['age'] using $arr joining str ['jimmy']['age']
```

Comment: explain what you think `$arr$x` means, please. If, while you try to do so, you realise what you did wrong, there is no shame in removing this question.

Comment: You can't do it like you are trying, `$x` contains a string which looks like array notation.

Comment: try this : echo $arr.$x;

Comment: @Rohit, it won't work like you said to try `$arr.$x`.

Comment: It would with `eval()`, but there's too much drama attached to that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to walk the array and keep track of each level with references:

```
$str ='jimmy.age';
$keys_tree = explode('.', $str);

$pointer = $arr;

while($key = array_shift($keys_tree)){

  if(!isset($pointer[$key]))
    throw new Exception(sprintf("Key %s doesn't exist", $key));

  $pointer = &$pointer[$key];      
}

echo $pointer;
```